# python vigenere problem with defining vigenere

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to define the function `vigenere` to implement in the program above but error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

```
#checking for upper case and lower case by applying formula for chr and ord and implementing function vigenere

def vigenere(c, k):

     if c.isupper():
         return chr(((ord(c)-65 +ord(k) for x in k-65)%26)+65)
     else:
         return chr(((ord(c)-97 +ord(k) for x in k-97)%26)+97)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your variable `k` is a string. I think that the error message is quite clear to be honest. What is the exact purpose of `k`? Maybe `ord(k)` or `chr(k)` would work? Either that, or `k` has to be an integer.

Comment: the purpose of defining this function vigenere is to use above in the program to implement vigenere. But when i use ord(k) the error is "TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found"

Comment: while chr(k) gives "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)" My purpose is that it should iterate over the whole key input by user